# Get time of day as a value between 0 and 1 from system time

Tags: date, math, time

I'm unable to find documentation on how to correctly extract the time of day as a value between 0 and 1 from the system clock. Meaning `0` is midnight, `0.25` is 6 AM, `0.5` is midday, `0.75` is 6 PM, `1` is midnight again. I have access to either the Unix time (milliseconds passed since 01-01-1970) or the hour:minute:seconds values independently... either can be used, I wouldn't mind knowing the math for both approaches so the solution is compatible with any scripting language I may use this for.

Comment: Given the time as `hh:mm:ss` you need to calculate `(1/24)*(hh+mm/60+ss/(60^2))`.

Comment: Seems to be working well, thanks!